# Angular2 - post sending a Null value

Tags: angular

Im getting a null value sent into the form body when i do a http post.  This is my service

```
    addRatings(ratings: IMeasureRating[]) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log("Add Rating service: " + JSON.stringify(ratings));

    this._http.post(this._ratingURL + "AddNewMeasureRatings", JSON.stringify(ratings), options)
        .map(res=> res.json()).subscribe();
}
```

ratings appears to be correctly populated if i step through this in debugger.  But my controller receives a null value.  This is my controller...

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public void AddNewMeasureRatings([FromBody] MeasureRating[] ratings)
    {
         _repository.AddRatings(ratings);
    }
```

Ive tried various combinations of .map and .toPromise.  All make the call to the controller but ratings is never populated when it gets there!

Comment: Can you see if your request body is correctly populated?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify the value you pass into post. If you pass in an object it should automatically post it as JSON.

```
    addRatings(ratings: IMeasureRating[]) {
        this._http.post(this._ratingURL + "AddNewMeasureRatings", ratings)
                  .map(res=> res.json()).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
    }
```

Comment: yes ive tried with stringify and without , no difference.

Comment: Change [HttpPost("[action]")] to just [HttpPost]